# custom error page endless loop in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-errors

net in asp.net with visual studio.
I am trying to put a custom error page i used this code -

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/errorPage.aspx" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/NotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

and i created the error pages.
i also got on the global.asax page this code -

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


    Dim mailClass As New MultiUseFunctions()

    Dim objErr As SystemException = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()
    Dim errorContent As String =  the error msg code  
    mailClass.sendMail(errorContent, "User Error Info", "the mail address", "Nothing")

End Sub
```

I do get the erorr msg in my mail but -->

Now this is my problem : 
When i am hitting an error for example bad url type and redirected to the notFound error page i get stuck in there maybe in an endless loop?  no matter what i click the website aint moving to other pages it just stuck on that page. 
Any idea what may cause such a thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you get stuck to the `NotFound.aspx` page, check whether the links the page contains are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this when the URL to the error page isn't correct. You get a 404, and then you try to go to a bad URL for the error page, which in turn triggers another 404, which tries to redirect to a bad url...ad infinitum.

Try browsing to your error page and make sure you've got the URL correct in your config setting.

Comment: Side note - on a web site, I don't think error emails are a good idea. On a busy day you could get FLOODED with error emails...

Comment: I changed to html error pages to make sure they always show up and then i checked the url and indeed it was wrong!